# How can I send the value of the id through ajax and PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I want to pass value of the id of the product to cart.php by using AJAX and display it in a div.cart in index.php but I have no idea how. please help.

Product

Product Description

Add to Cart

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
   $.ajax({
            url: 
            data:
         })
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can :) !

So first, let's get things straight. You're showing a list of products as `<div class="thumbnail">` form, right ? So your PHP/HTML should look a bit like this in reality :

```
<?php
foreach($database_recordset as $row) {
    echo '
    <div class="thumbnail>
        <img src="'.$row['img_src'].'" alt="'.$row['img_alt'].'" />
        <div class="caption">
            <h4>'.$row['product_name'].'</h4>
            <p>'.$row['product_description'].'</p>
            <a id="p-'.$row['id'].'" onclick="addCart(this)">Add to Cart</a>
        </div> <!-- You were missing a /div here if I guessed right the structure -->
    </div>';
}
?>
```

so I simply labelled the link `p-#ID` where #ID is the id of the product from the database and added an `onclick` event with `this` as the argument. Now you need a function `addCart` that will contain the AJAX request.

```
<script type="text/javacscript">
function addCart(elm) {
    // First we need the clean ID of the product
    var id = elm.id.split('-')[1]; // We split with '-' as separator and take the second element of the resulting array
    $.ajax({
        url: "cart.php",
        type: "POST", // or GET whatever but POST is usually better
        data: { id: id },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.status == 'OK') { // You should always test the response of an ajax request
                // show a message, update the cart icon or whatever
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify you code something like this. Href need to be removed else it will redirect you on that page. Give below is a sample of your code

```
<div class="thumbnail>
<img src="" alt="" />
<div class="caption">
<h4>Product</h4>
<p>Product Description</p>
<a id="id=(id from table products)">Add to Cart</a>
</div>

$('a').on('click', function(e){
$.ajax({
url: cart.php
data:{id:$(this).attr("id")}
})
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the browser following the link, then make an ajax request and insert the response into the target div.

You can use jquerys `load` method to acheive that in a single call:

```
$('a.clickme').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('div.cart').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Note i added a class to the link, else your code would capture all link clicks including site navigation etc

```
<a href="cart.php?id=(id from table products)" class="clickme">Add to Cart</a>
```

Comment: sir I successfully got response from cart.php it returns object. Sir how can I access the data returned from cart.php and display it in a cart div?